# Clustering in real life world problems

Tags: clustering, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset related to real estate  Market with features as price, area, number of bedrooms, bathrooms, and zip code. I want to group them in 4 different groups for each zip code. So, I used k-means clustering with 4 groups. Now, how can I explain the results to the business team? They are asking:

1. How reliable is this grouping?
2. How did I decide the threshold while grouping them together?

It makes me wonder if there exists any other way by which they can be grouped together.

Comment: The business team are asking good questions! Many statistical people here would like to swap their business team with your business team.

Comment: What kind of grouping do you want to have? What information do you want out of it? What kind of business decision is it supposed to support? There are an infinite ways of grouping this, the approach depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: @jonnor I want to group the houses into 4 different groups for targeting different groups of customers so that we can send promotional offers to them. For example group 4 can be a rich customer ( he is more interested in Expensive and big houses) as compared to group 1 consists of relatively poor people ( Less expensive and small houses ). One way of doing is to Hardcore define threshold with help of business ,such as  <100k , 2 bed, 1 bath as group 1 similarly for others. I was wondering if it is possible with Clustering without hardcore defining them.

Comment: What you are talking about is customer segmentation/targeted marketing/product suggetions. If you want to learn that from data, you should probably learn it from customer preferences (demand side)  - not from housing data (supply side). Typical data used would be typical searches etc. Once you know what potential customer (groups) are interested in, then you can just filter the housing data based on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the data from demand side. That's why I was forced to work with housing data.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely to be complete statistical nonsense.

Because all variables are different. And **computing differences of zip codes is pretty much nonsense**.

Obviously, a difference of 1 in the zip code is not equivalent to a difference of 1 in the number of bedrooms.

It's *not* enough to just throw an algorithm at some data, but the data needs to be prepared in a way that the *right* problem is optimized. So k-means did its job - but you asked the wrong question.  "How do I minimize variance in zip codes plus bedrooms?" is not a good question.

Comment: Hi, You're right about the zipcodes. I only used Price, area, no of bedroom, bathrooms after normalization for clustering. I computed 4 clusters for every Zip code.I didn't include zip codes in the data itself.

Comment: Nevertheless your features have very different meanings. So what is the meaning of the function you optimized?

Comment: Even normalization (whatever that means precisely) isn't guaranteed to make k-means defensible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I highly appreciate it. @Anony-Mousse, apologies, but when you say very different meanings. Does this mean they should have same measurements. For example, If i have similar features like (no. of bed, no. of bath, no. of garage) OR (area of bed, area of bath, area of garage) then I can cluster them ? The data-set given in question has mix of all kinds of features so i can't use K-Means here?Sorry I am still kind of new to this area.

Comment: You can use whatever you want. And you can interpret what you can interpret. That sounds banal, but the point is that this is a *choice* that you make, essentially how to weight one bed squared vs. one pool squared vs. one dollar squared. There is no right. But you may or may not be able to argue that the result is meaningful for your use case.